# Can I use IronPython to develop GUIs for Google App Engine?

Tags: python, user-interface, google-app-engine, ironpython

I'm developing a simple Python program with a (dynamic) form interface, but it needs to run on Google App Engine. I understand that IronPython lets one use Visual Studio's drag-and-drop interface builder and classes while programming with Python, but will this be compatible with Google App Engine?

Comment: what kind of GUIs would you run on a hosting service!?!?

Answer (score 3):

Google's Google App Engine can only run pure python code, and not even all Python is supported.  No, you can't do things like IronPython.

If you want to use Python, I'd learn Django.  If you want something closer to .NET, I'd go with Java.

Comment: I agree with MStodd. I would add that while you might be able to use Web Forms designer to create a skeleton of HTML that you could leverage, it would not be worth your time. You would end up spending more time removing scads of ASP.NET-specific markup. Web Forms designer is of very little use when you are doing anything besides creating ASp.NET applications.